# writing to a specific register in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using `PySerial` and `Python 2.7`, is it possible to write directly to a register on a chip through a serial port?

For instance, if I need to change a bit in register address `3E`, how would I do so?

Comment: You do not set registers directly though a serial port. There must be some kind of protocol, e.g. Modbus, on top of the serial interface for that to happen. You need to find out more about the device your talking about.

Comment: I will be communicating to it I2C if that is what you mean. Can you point me in the direction of some good examples? I am looking but I cannot find any